# Where do I find the source code for packages that I import in Java?

Tags: java, import, package

When I import a package, say e.g. `import java.awt.Graphics`, where can I find the source code for the Graphics class in my JDK installation on my Mac? I know the path to my installation is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, however I don't really understand exactly where the class is being generated from in the installation.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I don't really understand exactly where the class is being generated from"* It is not being generated from anywhere, it has already been compiled.

Comment: Just Google "java.awt.Graphics source".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a modern IDE, such as IntelliJ, along with a build tool such as Maven or Gradle, you should actually be able to just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CLICK</kbd> on any method in the `java.awt.Graphics` package to view the decompiled source code.  Developing using an IDE with something like Maven is recommended in most cases, so if you are not already doing so, now might be a good time to upgrade.

Comment: In Eclipse, you press F3 with cursor on the method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim! I'm using VSCode /w Maven, and can see the source code through the IDE, however I was more so hoping to find the path in my folders to see how java packages their libraries

Comment: @Mirage24 IntelliJ also shows you this.  Click on the package locator icon on the left top of your screen, and it will open the corresponding JAR in the tree, revealing the full path.

Comment: in inteliJ : 
u have line where u import like 
import at.campusonline.pub.desktop.rest.MyDesktopHooksRestService; and u click on MyDesktopHooksRestService and then ctrl + left click, then u will need to confirm decompilation , and then u will se source code !